# behavior of javascript 'this' keyword in closure

Tags: javascript, closures

Consider a simple pattern where we call setTimeout within a loop to print the loop counter:

```
function g(i){
    return function()
    {
        console.log(i);
    }
}

for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    setTimeout(g(i),3000);
}
```

This returns the expected result:

```
0
1
2
3
```

According to my understanding, this function should do the same thing

```
function f(i){
    this.n = i;
    return function()
    {
        console.log(this.n);
    }
}

for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    setTimeout(f(i),3000);
}
```

Instead, I get varying results, in NodeJS:

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

And in Google Chrome:

```
3
3
3
3
```

Neither of these results make sense to me, so I was hoping someone else can explain this to me.

Comment: No. `var n = i;` and `console.log(n)` would have worked. `this` is a completely different animal.

Comment: Why are you using `this` without calling a constructor? What do you expect to happen? Note that your code will throw in strict mode. And you should be using strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an arrow function to keep your this:

```
function g(i){
    return () =>
    {
        console.log(i);
    }
}

for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    setTimeout(g(i),3000);
}
```